# How to play multiplayer online with a SNES emulator?

Tags: emulation, snes

Is there a way to play online with SNES emulators? I tried SNESbox but it was really slow, to the point of being unplayable. I want to play multiplayer over the internet, with friends in another country.

Comment: SNES has no lag compensation. The games weren't *designed* to handle high latency, such as playing across countries. No solution is going to be good for doing what you're looking to do.

Comment: Damn. I imagine that, but I read some comments almost saying something like you could play online without lag. But well, what a shame. Thanks for the help, man.

Comment: You *can* play online "without lag". I've played with some friends via SNESbox prior without much of an issue. However these friends were in the same city, behind the same ISP, with a latency of ~30ms between us. The further that latency goes up however, the worse it's going to get.

Comment: @Thebluefish An answer along those lines, kinda "you can, but you have to have really low latency," would probably be a good answer.